# How to run a redirection python script on cpanel shared server such that it triggers on website page visit?

Tags: python, url, redirect

In short, I am trying to run an URL redirection python script on a shared server via cPanel's Setup Python App.

The app seems to work with no errors, but its not redirecting.

For example, the python app is setup on this domain: https://example.com/

The script states that if a corresponding redirect_path is visited, it will be redirected to the destination URL. For example, if ebay is my redirect_path, then visiting https://example.com/ebay will lead me to the set destination URL (e.g. https://ebay.com/)

I am used to using folders inside the File Manager to set the redirection paths (i.e. website pages), but I am trying to have the one python script to list all of the redirection paths and their corresponding destination URL's in one place with no folders.

It may be a newbie question, but how do I set up this python script on my domain (say https://example.com/), so that even when I visit https://example.com/ebay or https://example.com/google, it will execute the script?